# Generics and explicit/implicit operators

Tags: c#, generics, casting, operators

Consider the following scenario.

I have a method which returns `ISomething`, but it could be `Something` or `Wrapped<Something>`.
I therefore cast the result to `Something` to use it, but it fails, any help as to why or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new DerivedSomething();
        var b = (DerivedSomething)new Wrapped<DerivedSomething>(a); //success
        var c = (DerivedSomething)_GetSomething(false); //success, obsiously!
        var d = (DerivedSomething)_GetSomething(true); //Unable to cast object of type 'test_bed.Wrapped`1[test_bed.DerivedSomething]' to type 'test_bed.DerivedSomething'.
        var e = (DerivedSomething)(ISomething)new Wrapped<DerivedSomething>(a);  //Unable to cast object of type 'test_bed.Wrapped`1[test_bed.DerivedSomething]' to type 'test_bed.DerivedSomething'.

        var works = ((DerivedSomething)_GetSomething(false)).DoSomethingElse(); 
        var fails = ((DerivedSomething)_GetSomething(true)).DoSomethingElse(); //cast exception
    }

    private static ISomething _GetSomething(bool wrap)
    {
        var something = new DerivedSomething();
        return wrap ? new Wrapped<DerivedSomething>(something) : (ISomething)something;
    }
}

public interface ISomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public abstract class Something : ISomething
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //some code
    }
}

public class DerivedSomething : Something
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //some code
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        //some code
    }
}

public class Wrapped<T> : ISomething
    where T : ISomething
{
    private readonly T _something;

    public Wrapped(T something)
    {
        _something = something;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _something.DoSomething();
    }

    public static explicit operator T(Wrapped<T> wrapped)
    {
        return wrapped._something;
    }
}
```

It appears that if the type is exposed as the interface when trying to cast, then the operator is not found?

The 'easy' solution would be to write a 'unwrap' function which optionally unwraps the `Wrapped<Something>` to `Something`, but i'd prefer to use operators if possible.

**Edit**

I think the crux of the problem is: outside of `_GetSomething()` i wont know whether `Something` or `Wrapped<Something>` is going to be returned.

Comment: I don't think that `Wrapped<Something>` can be cast to `Something`.  I compiled your example, and verified that.  The first cast (variable `b`) should fail....

Comment: I guess you are asking why doesn't `explicit operator T(Wrapped<T> wrapped)` allow the cast to the passed concrete type and not just the constrained type.

Comment: @EthanBrown - The explicit cast is designed to perform the casting, it works correctly in case B, the question is why it doesn't work for case D or E

Comment: `I therefore cast the result to Something to use it`: Why do you need to downcast to `Something` in the first place? The fact that it and `Wrapped<T>` both implement `ISomething` is a clear indication that at least to some extent they should be indistinguishable.

Comment: @Anton, hopefully the revised code in the question highlights my problem a little better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cast operator looks like this:

```
public static explicit operator T(Wrapped<T> wrapped)
{
        return wrapped._something;
}
```

and you're casting like

```
var d = (Something)_GetSomething(true); //FAILS!
```

You can not cast to `Something` , cause `Something` is a *concrete implementation* of the `T:ISomething`. TO make this work you need to write:

```
var d = (ISomething)_GetSomething(true); //SUCCESS!
```

**or**

if you *really* want to use *concrete* type, you can define generic like:

```
public class Wrapped<T> : Something //Something and NOT ISomething 
    where T : ISomething
{
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: Tigran, `_GetSomething()` already emits `ISomething`, therefore the cast is unneccessary?

Comment: @SimonLaing: correct. I just show esplicitly that you need to change the definition of generic or use a double cast like in other posts provided here.

Comment: unfortunately `Something` relates to any number of classes which i am trying to wrap in a generic way. Therefore there would need to be as many `Wrapped<T>` classes as there are `Something` classes, something im keen to avoid!

Comment: @SimonLaing: ok, but at this point just *do not cast* to concrete type but use ISomething like an interface that refers to a concrete implementation.

Comment: Tigran, `ISomething` is the base interface, derived types are implemented with other methods. Therefore when these are required for use, the result will be cast from `ISomething` to the target type, e.g. `DerivedSomething`, This will pass if `_GetSomething(false)` is used, as its already a `DerivedSomething`; however when `Wrapped<DerivedSomething>` is returned, it will fail. Maybe i need to clarify my problem a little further?

Comment: @SimonLaing: I understand that.My point is that if you arhitect your code in OOP way, you *should* not need to have cast to concrete type, except rare cases. Cause all that concrete types share the same set of functions available in the ISomething. So if you write ISomething somethign = GetSomethign(); who cares abnout concrete type behind that? Just use something.

Comment: I've updated the question with a more 'production' like scenraio which is failing. Maybe it is a product of poor design, or maybe its genuinely not possible. As the operators are bound at compile time, what I'm finding confusing is that it works fine for scenario B but not D and E.

Comment: It works for B because the _compile-time type_ of the expression `new Wrapped<DerivedSomething>(a)` is (unsurprisingly) `Wrapped<DerivedSomething>`, on which an operator is defined. The compile-time type of `_GetSomething` is `ISomething`, on which no such operator is found, _at compile time_.

Comment: @Anton, I think i see what you mean. So even though the type is actually `Wrapped<DerivedSomething>` the CLR is using `ISomething` to work out the type conversion. It sounds like an `Unwrap` function may be the only way?

Comment: Pretty much. In B, the compiler sees `(DerivedSomething)(expression of Wrapped<DerivedSomething>)` and generates code to call the custom operator. In D and E, it sees `(DerivedSomething)(expression of ISomething)` and generates (C#-agnostic) code to try a runtime conversion, which doesn't use the operator (which is C# syntactic sugar). Without knowing more about your design, I couldn't say that `Unwrap` is the _only_ way. What about extending `ISomething` with the methods you need from `DerivedSomething`, or if that's impossible, introducing another interface?

Comment: @Anton, the ISomething refers to the very basics on a framework design. Therefore (almost without fail) every implemention of ISomething will have different properties/methods available, therefore there is no common interface i can produce.

Answer (score 4):

The explicit convert is bound at compile time (an extra hint is that the convert operator is static).

Try

```
var f = (Something)(Wrapped<Something>)_GetSomething(true);
```

This succeeds

In your case the compiler just knows that your type is `ISomething` and does not know how to convert an `ISomething` to a `Something` unless that happends to be a `Something` already.

By changing `public class Wrapped<T> : ISomething` to `public class Wrapped<T> : Something` your example execute fine, but your cast is not invoked since `Wrapped<T>` is already a `T`.

**Note:**
The `explicit operator` is not a cast, but a type conversion, it a method called and that method is resolved based on the compile time type (in your case `ISomething`). It is a source of confusion that type conversion has the same syntax as type casting. Casting is just assigning an existing object to a different variable of a compatible type while type conversion actually returns a new object.

Comment: Albin, your example would work, except for the scenario where false is passed to _GetSomething(). In this case `Something` could not be converted to `Wrapped<Something>`.

Comment: My scenario requires that `Wrapped<T>` does not inherit, it purely consumes `T`. Is the compiler only understanding the type by its exposed type (`ISomething` - as the return from `_GetSomething()`) rather than actual type emited from the method?

Comment: @SimonLaing, you can not, because the type must be known at compile time (by having a variable of type or casting). I updated my answer with some notes about the difference between casting and conversion.

Comment: @SimonLaing, when you have created your interface `ISomething` you better use that interface all the way along instead of trying to convert to a concrete type.

Comment: I think type conversion is what i require here, as i'm introducing a method to dictate how to convert `Wrapped<T>` to `T`. Is there a way to achieve the desired result without changing the type hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = (Something)(Wrapped<Something>)_GetSomething(true); 
var e = (Something)new Wrapped<Something>(a);
```

Comment: Danny, your example would work, except for the scenario where false is passed to `_GetSomething()`. In this case `Something` could not be converted to `Wrapped<Something>`